# Como crear un proyecto de Control de Usuario WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Necesito crear un Control de Usuario para una aplicacion .NET 3.5 en winforms bajo Visual Studio 2015 como un proyecto aparte, he visto que es sencillo añadir uno desde un proyecto, sin embargo como proyecto no encuentro la manera.

Cuando voy a crear un proyecto de este tipo me aparece la opcion para hacerlo en WPF pero no en Winforms clasico.

Esta es la pantalla de creacion de proyectos que me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, en la imagen que pusiste es la última opción, Windows Forma Control Library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes la plantilla de "Windows Forms Control Library" que es para crear una librería de controles de Windows Forms. En la librería puedes crear uno o varios controles.